# Should I classify the homebrew race I'm working on as a large race?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, races, creature-size

These are bug-people, who can wield normally-sized weapons (they have 2 sets of small hands). They are typically about 9 feet in height. Should I, and would it be a wise choice to, classify them as a large race?

Comment: Related: [Are there any rules or guidelines for large character races?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69967/33707)

Answer (score 20):

### WotC didn't, so you shouldn't either.

There are currently no WOTC-produced player character races that are Large. I could speculate as to the reasons, but I have no designer-quote evidence to support it.

[One answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69969/22138) to [Are there any rules or guidelines for large character races?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69967/are-there-any-rules-or-guidelines-for-large-character-races) does bring up some good points, however.

### What WotC did instead.

Player character races that are significantly larger than human size (bugbear and goliath immediately come to mind) have a trait that allows them to count as Large, but only for the purposes of lifting, carrying, and pushing - ***Powerful Build***.

Even the centaur, a traditionally horse-sized creature (definitely Large) is medium size in the player character version. They too have a similar trait for carrying capacity, though their version includes a drawback to and so has a different name (***Equine Build***).